# Is dockerize and a command in docker? When do people use dockerize as a keyword command?

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker and I'm confused about a line of bash scripting code regarding docker:

```
docker_start()
{
    container=$1
    log "Starting $container container...";
    docker start myproduct--$container
}

nginx_init()
{
    echo -e "\nwait for scorm engine and player\n"
    dockerize -wait tcp://player:8080 -wait tcp://scorm:8080 -timeout 90s
    docker_start "nginx"

    # just make sure their nginx.conf is right
    log "Updating nginx config: S3 Bucket: $S3_BUCKET..."
}
```

So, in the above code, what does `dockerize -wait ... -wait ... -timeout ...` do?

I tried to find the documentation for the command `dockerize` but I couldn't find any useful information.

Can someone elaborate? I think it is just something simple but I'm kinda stuck with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not a built-in docker command.

Maybe the author of the script has used the [dockerize project](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize)

So, to directly answer your question, it waits for other dependencies (player, scorm) to be started before proceeding as specified [in the documentation](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize#waiting-for-other-dependencies)